# jq filter query based on inner array items

Tags: json, select, jq

I have a json as

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "author": "hippy",
    "reviewers": [
      {
        "name": "hippy",
        "status": "ok"
      },
      {
        "name": "other",
        "status": "ok"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "author": "hippy",
    "reviewers": [
      {
        "name": "hippy",
        "status": "ok"
      },
      {
        "name": "build",
        "status": "ok"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "author": "hippy",
    "reviewers": [
      {
        "name": "hippy",
        "status": "ok"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "author": "other",
    "reviewers": [
      {
        "name": "hippy",
        "status": "ok"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I want to get the items where the `reviewer` is the same as `author` after excluding the reviewer `build`.

i.e. I want to get items with `id`s 2, 3.

I was able to get so far

```
.[] 
| select(
    .author as $author 
    | {reviewers} 
    | .[] 
    | map(.name) 
    | select(.[] == $author)
    )
```

but item with `id` 1 is false positive and I want to filter that out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description and the fact that you only want the two items, I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
.[]
| select( .author as $author
          | .reviewers
          | map(select(.name != "build"))        # ignore "build"
          | length==1 and .[0].name == $author )
```